# How does keras handle multiple losses?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, backpropagation, loss-function

If I have something like:

```python
model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = [y1,y2])

l1 = 0.5
l2 = 0.3
model.compile(loss = [loss1,loss2], loss_weights = [l1,l2], ...)
```

what does Keras do with the losses to obtain the final loss?
Is it something like:

```python
final_loss = l1*loss1 + l2*loss2
```

Also, what does it mean during training? Is the loss2 only used to update the weights on layers where y2 comes from? Or is it used for all the model's layers?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From [`model` documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/):

> **loss**: String (name of objective function) or objective function. See losses. If the model has multiple outputs, you can use a different loss on each output by passing a dictionary or a list of losses. The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the sum of all individual losses.
>
> ...
>
> **loss_weights**: Optional list or dictionary specifying scalar coefficients (Python floats) to weight the loss contributions of different model outputs. The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the weighted sum of all individual losses, weighted by the `loss_weights` coefficients. If a list, it is expected to have a 1:1 mapping to the model's outputs. If a tensor, it is expected to map output names (strings) to scalar coefficients.

So, yes, the final loss will be the "weighted sum of all individual losses, weighted by the `loss_weights` coeffiecients".

You can check the [code where the loss is calculated](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/9118ea65f40874e915dd1299efd1cc3a7ca2c333/keras/engine/training.py#L816-L848).

> Also, what does it mean during training? Is the loss2 only used to update the weights on layers where y2 comes from? Or is it used for all the model's layers?

The weights are updated through [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation), so each loss will affect only layers that connect the input to the loss.

For example:

```
                        +----+         
                        > C  |-->loss1 
                       /+----+         
                      /                
                     /                 
    +----+    +----+/                  
 -->| A  |--->| B  |\                  
    +----+    +----+ \                 
                      \                
                       \+----+         
                        > D  |-->loss2 
                        +----+
```

- `loss1` will affect A, B, and C.
- `loss2` will affect A, B, and D.

Comment: PAY ATTENTION!!! from the documentation: 'If the model has multiple outputs... The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the sum of all individual losses' (as reasonable) https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile so the final loss will affect ALL

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Notice that " the sum of all individual losses" , loss1 part of total loss has gradient only with A B C not D, and loss2 part of total loss has gradient only with A B D not C.

Answer (score 15):

**For multiple outputs to back propagate, I think it is not a complete answer from what's mentioned by Fábio Perez.**

> Also, what does it mean during training? Is the loss2 only used to
>   update the weights on layers where y2 comes from? Or is it used for
>   all the model's layers?

For output C and output D, keras will compute a final loss F_loss=w1 * loss1 + w2 * loss2. And then, the final loss F_loss is applied to both output C and output D. Finally comes the backpropagation from output C and output D using the same F_loss to back propagate.

Comment: only w1*loss1 part have gradient with C and only w2*loss2 part have gradient with D

Answer (score 0):

what happens behind `model.fit`?

loss calculation:

```py
loss_values = [] 
for loss_obj, loss_weight in zip(*zip_args):
    loss_value *= loss_weight
    loss_values.append(loss_value)
    reg_loss = math_ops.add_n(regularization_losses)
    loss_values.append(reg_loss)
total_loss = math_ops.add_n(loss_values)
```

Gradient calculate and weight update:

```py
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))
```

Notice that `tape.gradient will auto gradient, here` loss `is the node in graph, auto gradient will trace all gradient in the graph，`total_loss = loss1 + loss2`

[image: $$ \begin{aligned} \frac{\partial{loss1}}{\partial{D}} &= 0 \ \frac{\partial{loss2}}{\partial{C}} &= 0 \end{aligned} $$]

so:

- loss1 will affect A, B, and C.
- loss2 will affect A, B, and D.