# How can we apply a constraint to the value of a custom trainable variable?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, constraints, tensorflow2.0

I have defined a custom variable for a certain layer. I would like this variable to take only positive values. Keras provides constraints, but it seems to me that they are only meant for the `kernel_constraint` and `bias_constraint` parameters of the Keras' layers.

Is there a (simple) way of constraining the value of a custom trainable variable (i.e. one created with the method `add_weight`) in Keras (and TensorFlow)?

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add to the answer given by @xdurch0 that you if you want them to be non-negative, there is already the built-in [`NonNeg`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/constraints/NonNeg) constraint which exactly do this and you can use it as follow:

```
self.add_weight(..., constraint=tf.keras.constraints.NonNeg())
```

Comment: Will the constraint be satisfied even if the variable is trainable?

Comment: @nbro If you mean would it be applied for trainable variables, then the answer is yes. However, if you mean is it done by the gradient-based optimization (i.e. backpropagation), then I don't think that would be the case simply because it could not be formulated as a differentiable operation. Rather, I think it's applied after update of the weights; [the implementation of it](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/constraints.py#L66) also suggests this.

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow variables support constraints, and this includes variables created via `add_weight`. See the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#add_weight).

For example, if you want to force a variable to have values 0 < x < 1:

```
self.add_weight(shape=some_shape, constraint=lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, 0, 1))
```

In general, `constraint` should be a function; this function will take the variable as input and returns a new value for the variable. In this case, clipped at 0 and 1.

Note that the way this is implemented is that this function is simply called on the variable after the optimizer does its gradient step. This means that values that "want" to be outside the range will be clipped to hard 0s and 1s, and you might end up with lots of values precisely at this boundary. So as @y.selivonchyk notes, this is not "mathematically sound", i.e. the gradients don't know about the constraint. You might want to combine the constraint with the regularization they propose for the best effect.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely to have a strict mathematicly-sound way to keep gradients for that variable to never push it below zero. Yet, you can add prior to your model, which would be: "Variable X should stay non-negative" and increase loss whenever this prior does not hold. The way to do it would be to:

1. Calculate a mathematical expression that would be positive only when your var is negative, which would be something along the lines of `K.sum(K.relu(-var))`
2. Expose the result of this expression as a second output of the model
3. Apply a linear loss to this output, which would be summed up with your training loss (you can provide a weight for [this summation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404309/how-does-keras-handle-multiple-losses))

This solution would have drawbacks: some of the components might still be negative after an iteration, since "regularizing" gradient would be lagging behind by one iteration (may be remedied with a more strict rule `K.sum(K.relu(-var+1))`; depending on your loss weight you might end up zeroing out components of this variable.

Comment: Note that you can directly add "regularization losses" with Keras models, so there is no way to expose this term as an output.