# How to get the intermediate results from loss function in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics, loss-function

I'm writing a customized loss function, it looks like this:

> loss = w1 * score1 + w2 * score2 + w3 * score3

I could see the final score (loss) in the process of model.fit now.
But I would like to see the `score1`, `score2`, `score3` as well.

How could I see the `score1`, `score2`, `score3` results?

Ps. I know I could split the code and write multiple separate metric functions. But it will run the same calculation process twice (one for loss, one for metric). And the calculation of `score1`, `score2`, `score3` is very time-consuming. Is there a better way for this task? Like pass some parameters from loss to metric? Or to history?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass separate loss functions to model.compile, along with their weights w1, w2, w3. This way, each individual loss term will be printed to the log along with their sum. For example:

```
model.compile(loss=[score1_fn, score2_fn, score3_fn], loss_weights=[w1, w2, w3], ...)
```

See [How does keras handle multiple losses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404309/how-does-keras-handle-multiple-losses) for more details

Comment: Thanks. But my functions `score1, score2, score3` share the same preprocess code. So in this way, the preprocess code will be run multiple times... It till cost much more time...